# Can I target any number of creatures, even if the ability would have no effect?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Aurelia's Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAurelia%27s%5d%2b%5bFury%5d) and other spells like it allow me to choose any number of targets. As written, it implies I can choose more than X targets.

Can I, for instance, cast [Aurelia's Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAurelia%27s%5d%2b%5bFury%5d) where X = 5 and target 5 of my opponent's creatures, as well as all of my heroic creatures, and then choose to deal one damage to each of my opponent's creatures (leaving my creatures unharmed)? Or am I required to choose targets in some way such that the spell affects them (if possible)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No.**

> 601.2d If the spell requires the player to divide or distribute an effect (such as damage or counters) among one or more targets, the player announces the division. **Each of these targets must receive at least one of whatever is being divided.**

This is also mentioned in the Gatherer rulings for Aurelia's Fury:

> You announce the value of X and how the damage will be divided as part of casting Aurelia’s Fury. **Each chosen target must receive at least 1 damage.**

Comment: Could you cast Aurelia's Fury with X = 0 just for the sake of targeting all of your own Heroic creatures and not dealing any damage to any of them?

Comment: You cannot.  If you are dealing 0 damage, then you choose 0 targets because of the ruling mentioned above.

Comment: You could cast it for X=0, but it would be an untargetted spell at that point and do nothing when it resolves.